# Executing a Haskell file with cmd through Java

Tags: java, haskell, cmd

I am working on a project where I need to compile and execute a Haskell file over cmd which I start/control with Java. That is what it looks like now:

```
public class CmdTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\ray\\Documents\\Project\" && ghci ", "test.hs");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
}
```

So far so good. Then i tried to execute my actual haskell-function(testfunction) by writing it directly behind the "test.hs" and i tried to write "..."test.hs", "testfunction 2");" and many more way, but i cant load it, when i add any of those. Please tell me how i can fix it and get it running.
Thx for your time

Ray

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141148/best-way-to-call-haskell-functions-from-within-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370177/communication-between-java-and-haskell may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your file `test.hs` looks like

```hs
module Main where

testfunction :: Int -> IO ()
testFunction n = print n

main :: IO ()
main = do
    testfunction 2
```

Then you can call it without compilation from Java using the `runhaskell` command:

```java
public class CmdTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd.exe",
        "/c",
        "cd \"C:\\Users\\ray\\Documents\\Project\" && runhaskell ",
        "test.hs");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
}
```

The important parts to note:

Your Haskell file has to explicitly be `module Main` or have no module declaration (it's implicitly `Main`, but it's always good idea to be explicit), it has to have a function called `main` with type `IO ()`, and the use of the `runhaskell` command.  The `ghci` command is for running an interactive REPL, much like `IPython` or `irb`, it is not meant for running a source file as a script.  You also can't just specify which function inside the `.hs` file to run, your file has to be an executable.  You wouldn't expect this to work for Java

```java
// SayHello.java
public class SayHello {
    public static void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.print("Hello, ");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

And then run it as

```sh
> java SayHello.java SayHello.sayHello "World"
```

You have to compile it first and have the target function called from some `public static void main(String[] args)`.  The same goes for Haskell, you have to have a `main` function to run anything, and `runhaskell` will simply compile and run your code in one step.